# Odoo 8 onchange on inherited models

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a module that implements an onchange method on res.partner. If I create a new model that inherits res.partner, the onchange is not called. Is there a way to make the onchange general, so it's also called on inherited models?

Example:

```python
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.onchange('zip')
    def _valid_zip(self):
        print 'Validating zip...'

class ExtendedPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'extendedpartner'
    _inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}
```

If I change the zip code on an extendedpartner, the onchange is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use *delegation inheritance* in the code above. Delegation inheritance does not work on model methods. It just simply *delegates* lookup of fields not found in current model to the "parent" model.

I think what you want is prototype inheritence:

```
class ExtendedPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'extendedpartner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
```

The graphic below shows three types of inheritance available in Odoo:

[image: three types of inheritence avaliable in Odoo]

You currently use the first one ("classic inheritance") in `ResPartner` (which inherits from `res.partner`) and the last one (delegation inheritance) in `ExtendedPartner`. I think the middle one (Prototype inheritance) would be more appropriate for `ExtendedPartner`. It basically works in a manner very similar to standard Python inheritance.

You can read more about different types of inheritance [in the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html) (which is also the source of the image above).